# Installing Ubuntu on external USB drive

Tags: system-installation, uefi, external-hdd

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an external Toshiba 3.0 2TB hard drive, but after the install my computer will not boot to the hard drive. The computer doesn't even recognize the hard drive at all.

I have reformatted the drive using Windows and Ubuntu. I have reinstalled Ubuntu several times using the the automatic partitioning and by manually setting up the partitions myself. Nothing seems to work.

I also have changed my boot order to boot from USB before HDD in the UEFI options.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why my computer is not recognising the drive?

Thanks for your  time!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please update your question with the output of `sudo parted -l`.

Comment: UEFI only boots from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi on the ESP - efi system partition on external drive. Ubuntu installer only puts boot files in ESP on sda, so you have to copy /EFI/ubuntu to sdb and then copy again to /EFI/Boot and rename shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi. I just did this for my full install to a flash drive. You must gpt partition in advance to have an ESP on external drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If it is a USB 3 device, be aware many systems don't support booting off USB 3 and won't detect it as a viable option. Just plug it into a USB 2 port for testing in that case.